# Change project name in android studio 2.x and runs into error "settings.gradle" not found

Tags: android

I tried to use "refactor" to change the project name but runs into an error message box "settigns.gradle file not found". Why is that?

Comment: Try this out, Change the name that is shown in the title bar in the file ".idea/.name".

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change the project directory name directly. Same rule applied to the package name. for instance, if you want to change the package from "org.xyz.myApp" to "com.abc.newapp". Then change the directory under /src/java/org/xyz/myApp to /src/com/abc/newapp. In the source code, replace all package org.xyz.myApp by com.abc.newapp.